# Node.js version in Azure emulator outdated

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-roles

I set up a Cloud Service, wherein I specify the nodejs version for a WebRole in the `ServiceDefinition.csdef` like this:

```
<WebRole name="WebRole1">
 <Startup>
  <Task commandLine="setup_web.cmd &gt; log.txt" executionContext="elevated">
   <Environment>
      <Variable name="RUNTIMEID" value="node;iisnode" />
      <Variable name="RUNTIMEURL" value="http://az413943.vo.msecnd.net/node/0.10.21.exe;http://az413943.vo.msecnd.net/iisnode/0.1.21.exe" />
   </Environment>
[...]
```

While this enables Node 0.10.21 when run on Azure, I get an ancient 0.6.20 when I run this with the emulator.

Is this a known issue with the emulator? (Couldn't find anything) Or how can I ensure that the emulator also uses the required version?